# Update Status in Twitter via twitter4j Library - 401 Authontication Credentials... error

Tags: android, authentication, twitter, twitter4j

Hi I am trying to implement "status update" via twitter4j library.

However it am always getting the same error:

> 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth)
>   were missing or incorrect.
>
> Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock in in sync.
>
> TwitterException{exceptionCode=[6b80c41c-1bd1da85], statusCode=401,
>   retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null,
>   featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.5-SNAPSHOT(build:
>   5f9c44cd0e0c1972f8d17653a226b9b6a3392ac2)}
>   ...

Below you can find the code piece:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
        .setOAuthConsumerKey(cons_key)
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret(cons_secret)
        .setOAuthAccessToken(acc_token)
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(acc_secret);

        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
        twitter4j.Status status;
        try {
            status = twitter.updateStatus(params[0]);
            if (status.getId() == 0) {
                System.out.println("Error occured while posting tweets to twitter");
            }
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am pretty sure about I have the valid consumer/access tokens/secrets.

I don't know how to sync the system clock.

Do you have an idea what is the actual problem behind this error? I couldn't find any useful answer on internet.

Any help would be appreciated..
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try few things -

1. Regenerate the authentication keys for your registered app by logging in to https://apps.twitter.com.
2. Also ensure your registered application has Read/Write access to be able to post an status update.
3. I am not sure about clock sync on android, but for linux/Windows you can check 
   which NTP server to point your system to.

Also use latest version of twitter4j.

Comment: yes you need to update app permissions and regenerate authentication keys. If you don't regenerate authentication keys it doesn't work.